# How to save an object inside mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have created a form where i have certain fields.I also have a field that contains an array of fields within."req.body.lead" output of the field is as:

```
// output of console.log("req.body.lead",req.body.lead);
     business_address_attributes: 
      { address_type: 'Business',
        street1: 'Street 1...',
        street2: 'Street 2...',
        city: 'City...',
        state: 'State...',
        zipcode: 'Zip Code...',
        country: '' },
```

I can store the entire object inside another object as:

```
      var address = new Addresses(req.body.lead.business_address_attributes);
```

Inside  mongodb i have declared a field as:

```
   business_address_attributes : [Addresses],
   //Note: [Addresses] refers to address class
```

Now when i try to store the inside monogdb using following, I am getting error,unable to save lead

```
var lead = new Leads(req.body.lead);
var address = new Addresses(req.body.lead.business_address_attributes);
lead.business_address_attributes.$push(address);
lead.save();
// console.log(lead.business_address_attributes) now gives following output:
    [ { address_type: 'Business',
  street1: 'Street 1...',
  street2: 'Street 2...',
  city: 'City...',
  state: 'State...',
  zipcode: 'Zip Code...',
  country: '',
  _id: 4f857a2e491383dc64000008 } ]
```

I don't know how to solve the problem.Can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution of this problem was to declare the field with array of documents as a reference array.

Create a schema for `Address` document:

```
  var AddressSchema = new Schema({
     //attributes
  });
```

and create a model:

`mongoose.model('address', AddressSchema)`

Now in the parent document you can say

```
business_address_attributes : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'address' }]
```

When creating a new document, create Address document first, save it, get ID of a saved doc and push it into `lead.business_address_attributes`.

To get back a document with addresses instead of just IDs, use mongoose's `populate('business_address_attributes')` method.